# Material-UI drop-down menu causing error in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, material-ui, angular6

Unfortunately we have to support IE11.

The following is a snippet of Angular from our app:

```
<nav class="navbar-menu" fxFill>
    <span class="fill-it"></span>
    <span class="nav-user-wrap" fxFlexAlign="right">
        <button class="nav-user" mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="usrmenu">{{ userManager.currentDealer?.name }} <mat-icon class="icon-avatar">person</mat-icon><mat-icon class="icon-arrwdwn">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon></button>
        <mat-menu #usrmenu="matMenu" class="userdd mmdd" xPosition="after" yPosition="below" [overlapTrigger]="false">
            <span mat-menu-item [disabled]="true" [disableRipple]="true">{{ userManager.firstName }} {{ userManager.lastName }}</span>
            <mat-divider style="border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin: 0 16px;"></mat-divider>

            <span mat-menu-item *ngIf="!userManager.isDealerGroupUser" (click)="openSelectDealerGroupDialog()">{{ userManager.dealerGroup?.name }}</span>
            <mat-divider *ngIf="!userManager.isDealerGroupUser" style="border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin: 0 16px;"></mat-divider>

            <button *ngFor="let dealer of userManager.dealers" (click)="userManager.setCurrentDealer(dealer.id)" mat-menu-item>{{ dealer.name }} <span *ngIf="dealer.id === userManager.defaultDealer?.id">(Default)</span></button>

            <mat-divider style="border-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8); margin: 0 16px;"></mat-divider>
            <!-- <button mat-menu-item>My Account</button>
            <button mat-menu-item>Settings</button> -->
            <button mat-menu-item (click)="logOut()">Logout</button>
        </mat-menu>
    </span>
</nav>
```

Pretty standard drop-down menu, but in IE11 clicking the button gives the following exception:

```
Unable to get property 'opacity' of undefined or null reference
```

I'm pulling my hair out trying to work out why.
Does IE11 do some kind of pseudo-script thing in the background to set the CSS or something? No idea.

All help appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is a result of IE11 lacking the [Web Animation API](https://caniuse.com/#feat=web-animation), to fix this You have to import the right polyfill as documented in [Angular Docs](https://angular.io/guide/browser-support).

`import 'web-animations-js'`

Comment: Thanks- I'd forgotten about this old question!

Answer (score 1):

Angular docs say that you only need the 'web-animations-js' polyfill for IE if you use the AnimationBuilder, but my project doesn't use AnimationBuilder and I get this error message.  There's a possibility one of the libraries I'm using does. But I only started getting this error after I upgraded to Angular 8.

Comment: I also get the issue after updating to angular 8.0.0 and material 8.0.0. The web-animations-js polyfill doesn't seem to help. It worked fine for angular 7.2.x. Have you been able to fix it? Does the polyfill work for you?

Comment: @Tom I figured it out, just now.

`npm install --save core-js`

Then, in polyfills.ts, add back:
```import 'core-js/es/symbol'
import 'core-js/es/object'
import 'core-js/es/function'
import 'core-js/es/parse-int'
import 'core-js/es/parse-float'
import 'core-js/es/number'
import 'core-js/es/math'
import 'core-js/es/string'
import 'core-js/es/date'
import 'core-js/es/array'
// import 'core-js/es7/array';
import 'core-js/es/regexp'
import 'core-js/es/map'
import 'core-js/es/weak-map'
import 'core-js/es/set'```

Comment: Thanks, if I add `import 'core-js/es/symbol';` the issue is gone :) best solution so far. You are my hero of the day ;) But probably this is not the intended way as the polyfill should probably only be added in the es5 version of the polyfills.
I added a specific question [Material-UI drop-down menu causing error in IE11 after updating to angular 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56431642/material-ui-drop-down-menu-causing-error-in-ie11-after-updating-to-angular-8) yesterday I would welcome you to add you answer there so I can give you an upvote.