# Material-UI drop-down menu causing error in IE11 after updating to angular 8

Tags: angular, angular-material, internet-explorer-11, material-ui, angular8

Angular 8 application with material 8 throws following error on IE11 when the material menu is opened:

```
Unable to get property 'opacity' of undefined or null reference
```

It worked well with angular 7.2.
Used IE11 Version: 11.1146.16299.0 Update version: 11.0.125

New project dependency versions:

```
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/cdk": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/material": "^8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
"@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
"classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
"core-js": "^3.1.3",
"rxjs": "~6.5.2",
"tslib": "^1.9.0",
"web-animations-js": "github:angular/web-animations-js#release_pr208",
"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

}

Simple Menu

```
<mat-menu #appMenu="matMenu">
  <button mat-menu-item>Menu Item 1</button>
</mat-menu>

<button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="appMenu">
  Menu
</button>
```

Already used pollyfills:

```
import 'classlist.js';  // Run `npm install --save classlist.js`.
import 'web-animations-js'; // Run `npm install --save web-animations-js`.
```

IE stack trace:
[image: IE stack trace]

I verified the issue with a newly created angular 8 app containing only the menu in the app component.

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to solve this issue? Thanks

Comment: IE11 needs [all these polyfills](https://weblogs.asp.net/lduveau/angular-not-working-in-ie11) when running an Angular app. Try to edit the src/polyfills.ts file and try it again.

Comment: These are exactly the polyfills angular removed during the update to version 8. They can not be readed as they don't exist anymore. Including their new versions:
`import 'core-js/es/array';
import 'core-js/es/date';
import 'core-js/es/function';
import 'core-js/es/map';
import 'core-js/es/math';
import 'core-js/es/number';
import 'core-js/es/object';
import 'core-js/es/parse-float';
import 'core-js/es/parse-int';
import 'core-js/es/regexp';
import 'core-js/es/set';
import 'core-js/es/string';
import 'core-js/es/symbol';
import 'core-js/es/weak-map';` works ...

Comment: ... but I guess it is not the intended way. It would include the polyfills also in the es2015 version and one goal of the new differential loading build was to avoid this. Is there a polyfill which is only included in the es5 version?

Comment: The answer provided by @daktaklakpak works. I try to add import 'core-js/es/symbol'; to the polyfills.ts and the error disappears! You can mark the answer as an accepted answer. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding `import 'core-js/es/symbol';` to the polyfill

Comment: Note that this requires `core-js` v3.x, and installing it [will cause some issues](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13954). The v2.x equivalent is `import 'core-js/es6/symbol';`, which fixed the problem for me.